# java.lang.illegalArgumentException error while Uploading video To Firebase Database by Uri Of Video File in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to upload videos to firebase by getting video Uri from `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and from intent from another activity there user can select video from list of videos  .

From Both Two Ways  I got `java.lang.illegalArgumentException` Error.

In intent From Activity VideoView Plays Uri (Which I got From Activity Intent) But Not Uploading.

From `ACTION_SEND` videoview can't play uri of video file and video can't uploaded.

I am using Kotlin For this .

**Upload Video Activity** :

In this Activity I am getting Uri From Both `ACTION_SEND` and Uri From Activity
and as I told Before Video View could play uri from Intent Activity But can't play from `ACTION_SEND` uri.

```
     private lateinit var uploadBtn: Button
    private lateinit var vV: VideoView
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private val loadingDialog = Loadingdialog(this)
    private lateinit var mstorageref: StorageReference
    private lateinit var mDatabaseRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var pauseimg: CardView 
    private lateinit var startimg: CardView 
    private lateinit var videotring : TextView 
    private lateinit var TITLE: TextInputEditText 
    private lateinit var DESCRIPTION: TextInputEditText 
    private lateinit var vidocard:CardView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_for_video_namashiv)
        
        mstorageref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Commenting_Videos")
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Commenting_Videos")
        uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadVideo)
        pauseimg = findViewById(R.id.puseimg)
        startimg = findViewById(R.id.sartimg)
        videotring = findViewById(R.id.videostring)
        TITLE = findViewById(R.id.TITLE)
        DESCRIPTION =findViewById(R.id.DESCRIPTION)
        vidocard = findViewById(R.id.vidocard)
        pauseimg.visibility = View.GONE
        startimg.visibility = View.GONE
        vV = findViewById(R.id.videoView)
        imageUri = intent.getStringExtra("uri") as? Uri
        vidocard.visibility = View.GONE
        //Here is The Action Send URI 
        //From this Video View can play The Uri
        when{
            intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND ->{
            
            if(intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)){
                (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as Uri).let{
                vV.setVideoURI(it)
                vV.start()
                imageUri = it
                 }
            }
            else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a video to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               }
        }
    }
    
        val id: Long? = intent.extras?.getLong("videoId")

        imageUri = id?.let { ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, it) }
        vV.setVideoURI(imageUri)
        val mC = MediaController(this, true)
        vV.start()
         vV.setOnClickListener{

               val etrieve = MediaMetadataRetriever()
               //Here only I got Error Illegal Argument Exception
            etrieve.setDataSource(this, imageUri)
            val sit: Bitmap? = etrieve.frameAtTime
            val VideoString = if(sit!!.width > sit.height){
                "This Video Will Be Uploaded To COMMENTING HORIZONTAL"
            }else{
                "This Video Will Be Uploaded To COMMENTING PORTRAIT"
            }
             videotring.text = VideoString
         vidocard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
             Handler().postDelayed({
                 vidocard.visibility = View.GONE
             },5000)
             if(vV.isPlaying()){
                 vV.pause()
                 pauseimg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                 Handler().postDelayed({
                     pauseimg.visibility = View.GONE
                 },2000)

                 startimg.visibility = View.GONE
             }
             else
             {
                 vV.start()
                 startimg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                 Handler().postDelayed({
                     startimg.visibility = View.GONE
                 },2000)

                 pauseimg.visibility = View.GONE
             }

         }


        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if(imageUri == null) {
               createSnackbar("NO VIDEOS SELECTED ! ! !")
            }

            else if(TITLE.text.toString() == ""){
                createSnackbar("Enter Title")
            }

            else if(DESCRIPTION.text.toString() == ""){
                createSnackbar("Enter Description")
            }

            else {
                val int = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                int.putExtra("Title",
                    TITLE.text.toString())
                int.putExtra("Description",DESCRIPTION.text.toString())
                
                int.putExtra("videoId", imageUri)
                

                startActivity(int)

            }

        }
    }
```

**"Main Activity:"**
Here in this activity title ,description,video uri intented from Upload video activity to upload in firebase.
check comments in my code there I mentioned line where I got error .

```
        private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    
    //i am getting a uri from upload video activity
     val id: Long? = intent.extras?.getLong("videoId")
                imageUri = id?.let { ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, it) }
            
           val TITLE:String? = intent.extras?.getString("Title")
            val DESCRIPTION:String? = intent.extras?.getString("Description")
    
    
    if(imageUri == null) {
        //don't do anything
        
    }
    else{
    
    ui.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        if (TITLE != null && DESCRIPTION != null) {
            uploadfunction(TITLE,DESCRIPTION)
        }
    }


    private fun getExtension(uri: Uri): String? {
            val cr: ContentResolver = contentResolver
            val mime: MimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
            return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri))
        }
        
    private fun uploadfunction(TITLE:String,DESCRIPTION:String) {
        ui.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        var pathString: String
        if(imageUri != null) {
            val ref: StorageReference = mstorageref.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + "." +
                    getExtension(imageUri!!))
            val retrieve = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            //Here only i got illegal argument exception
            retrieve.setDataSource(this, imageUri)
            val bit: Bitmap? = retrieve.frameAtTime
            pathString = if(bit!!.width > bit.height){
                "NewFeatureVideo"
            }else{
                "Videos"
            }
            ref.putFile(imageUri!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener{taskSnapshot ->
          
                    val uriTask = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                    while (!uriTask.isSuccessful);
                    val downloadUri = uriTask.result
                    if (uriTask.isSuccessful){

                        val title = TITLE
                        val description = DESCRIPTION
                        val videoUri = "$downloadUri"
                        val imguri = auth.currentUser?.photoUrl.toString()
                        val vm = videomdel(title, videoUri,description,imguri)
                        val dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(pathString).push()
                        dbReference.setValue(vm)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {

                                createSnackbar("VIDEO UPLOADED !!!")
                                progressload.progress = 100
                                uplodtext.text = "Uploaded"

                               }
                            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                    }
                }
                
                .addOnProgressListener {
                    //convert total bytes to string
                val totalbytes : Double = it.totalByteCount.toDouble()
                val totbytmb = totalbytes/(1024*1024)
                    val bytes = totbytmb.roundToInt()
                val totbytstring = bytes.toString()
                    //convert transferred bytes to string
                    val transbytes : Double = it.bytesTransferred.toDouble()
                    val transmb = transbytes/(1024*1024)
                        val ytes = transmb.roundToInt()
                    val transstring = ytes.toString()
                       createSnackbar("Total Size : " + " " + totbytstring + "MB")
                    val progres: Double = (100*it.bytesTransferred)/it.totalByteCount.toDouble()
                    progressload.progress = progres.roundToInt() 
                    val pro = progres.roundToInt()
                    uplodtext.text = "Uploading $pro% " + "\n" + transstring + "/" + totbytstring
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {e ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

I have Lot of another unrelated code in MainActivity So I only added problem related code only
I also try do some changes but it didn't worked .
I Hope I added Enough Information About my problem if it didn't please tell me I could Edit And Please Help me to Solve This Problem .

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).